# generating password protected pdfs using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

Recently I was looking for some gem which can password protect our existing pdf files.

Basically we are fetching some invoice PDFS from `aws` .  After fetching it from aws , we have to add password to the pdf and send it as an attachment in an email.

I tried with `prawn/hexapdf/combined_pdf` , but no success. Because with prawn i can not find a way to read an existing pdf. but prawn can easily password encrypt any pdf generated via prawn.

Any suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: I think, you can try princexml https://www.princexml.com/ to set passwords for  your pdfs, but I don't know, can it be applied to existing files or not.

Prince for setting password from command line example
`--user-password=PASS`
https://www.princexml.com/doc/command-line/

Also I found gem which can merge pdfs, but I've no experince with it https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not really a gem, but is it possible to install and use a command line program like `pdftk`? I've been using it for years for similar problems with great success.